# What technology does Songza use to play continuous audio while navigating their site?

Tags: html, audio, audio-streaming

When I use Songza, I can navigate the site and the audio keeps on playing. What technology do they use to accomplish this. Pandora also does this. They both change full URLs as well.

Comment: these kind of thing can be done by send the data in small packets and play them

Comment: It's all one page.  The page doesn't change.  You can change the URL without changing the page.  Try it on an older browser, and you will note that only the hash changes.

Comment: Thanks Brad, sure enough IE8/9 both still use Hashtags while latest FF and Chrome work without Hashtags. This corresponds with what is said by the History.js guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't used Songza, but from what I can tell of Pandora, they don't actually change the site, it's all (more or less) on one page.

The content is changed using things like [jQuerys load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

The url is changed through javascript as well, with methods like [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

Comment: Very awesome! I read all about this and even the link from Mozilla to History.js and all the info about Hashtags and Google. This saved me countless hours of research. Very good stuff! Thanks ~ Elijah